# Jquery data selector not returning expected object

Tags: jquery

I have a form with a data-attribute:

```
<form data-test="true"></form>
```

I'm trying to target it using:

```
var form = $('form').data('test');
```

but when I log out **form** it just returns **True** and not the jquery object I was expecting.

http://jsfiddle.net/mbp3S/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use:

```
$("form[data-test='true']");
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mbp3S/2/)**